# Fazer um loop pra 2 labels ao clicar

Tags: c#, loop

Eu preciso de um *loop* para 2 *labels* onde cada uma aparece um texto já especificado no código. Apenas por curiosidade mesmo.
Eu queria um *loop* com o mesmo efeito que o código abaixo:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     lbl_1.Text = "Ziummmmmm";

     ++NumberOfClick;
     switch(NumberOfClick)
     {
          case 1:
              lbl_1.Text = "Ziummmmmm";
              break;
          case 2:
              lbl_2.Text = "Ploft";
              break;
          case 3:
              lbl_1.Text = "";
              lbl_2.Text = "";
              break;
     } 
}
```

Estou tentando fazer um *loop*, mas tá incompleto e não sei como continuar, qualquer ajuda eu aceito.

```
while (lbl_1.Text == "Ziummmmmm")
{
      lbl_2.Text = "Ploft";
      while (lbl_2.Text == "Ploft")
      {
           lbl_1.Text = "";
           lbl_2.Text = ""; 
      }              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A única razão pela qual você vê a alteração de um texto para o outro, é o fato de ela acontecer sob a condição de ocorrência de um evento (Que no caso é o de você clicar o botão do mouse). Se você alterar os textos em um loop, tudo o que você verá, será o último texto alterado/atualizado (Como não teve condição nenhuma pra "segurar" a alternância, nenhum evento, ele simplesmente se atualizou até o fim). Logo, o seu raciocínio não faz sentido.

Entretanto, você poderia fazer isso:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 3)
{
    if (i == 1)
    {
        lbl_1.Text = "Ziummmmmm";  
    } 
    else if (i == 2)
    {
        lbl_2.Text = "Ploft";  
    } 
    else if (i == 3)
    {
        lbl_1.Text = "";
        lbl_2.Text = "";
    }
    i++;
}
```

No seu primeiro exemplo, você atualiza a variável i (Que no caso é NumberOfClick) a cada click de mouse. Da maneira que quer, a variável é atualizada a cada iteração / loop. Ou seja, tudo o que você deverá ver no Label, por fim, são apenas os resultados finais, que no caso, são Strings vazias ("", "").

Comment: Agora eu entendi, muito obrigado cara, deu certo :D!!

Comment: Não esquece de aceitar a minha resposta como correta! huahua.